# What do these meta properties do?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

Noob question. I have a chrome extension that is throwing back funky results when it accesses an api.

I think the problem is with the user ID I'm scraping from the DOM.

What exactly are the purposes of these elements?

```
<meta name="twitter:app:url:googleplay" content="website://user/22457128">
<meta name="twitter:app:url:googleplay" content="website://user/22457128">

<meta property="fb:app_id" website="127876283963492">
<meta property="twitter:app:id:iphone" content="517684114">
<meta property="twitter:app:id:ipad" content="517684114">
<meta property="twitter:creator:id" content="385941344">
```

And why are some of the Ids at the end of them the same but others are different?

Comment: They show other sites how to display your website

Comment: Like how youtube has the nice looking box when a YouTube video is shared that's done with meta tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***They basically show other sites how to display your website.***

***Like if you share a YouTube video in Twitter or Facebook is shows all nice with the video title, thumbnail, length and all those great stuff. Its all done using meta tags.***

***Google use website meta tags to determine what the website is about and if it is appropriate.***

***Here is a link example:***

```
https://youtu.be/Luo_wCcWAaw
```

***The first two are the exact same that's why they're I'd is the same. They tell you the name of the website to Twitter.***

***Onto Property's***

***They tell you how the website should look on different devices and on different websites***

***iPhone property tells how the meta tag should look on iPhone.***

***IPad meta says how it should look on ipad.***

***Fb one says how it should look on Facebook.***